Driving an Objects animation from a Physics Simulation on another Object
I am a Blender beginner but very familiar with 3d workflow with a background in After Effects.
I have a very high poly/face count mesh Ball that I am trying to animate using simple physics simulation with a collision plane and softbody on the ball object.
Because of the amount of polys the ball acts as a sort of liquid and collapses in on itself even with rigidity turned up.
I have successfully created the animation using a low poly UV sphere, is there any way I can drive the animation of the High poly sphere with the low poly sphere as it seems that the X,Y & Z positions of the low poly sphere doesn't change when the simulation runs, so linking the transform properties with drivers doesn't seem to be effecting the main sphere.
In after effects I would link the properties of the models together and then it in theory would transfer the animation across, things appear to work a bit differently in blender so If anyone could recommend a solution. Ideally I would have the squash and stretch applied to the main sphere but at this point as long as I can transfer the XYZ position and rotation values to the target object from the source generated through the physics simulation, I'll take it.

Use a mesh deform modifier on your high poly model, choose the low poly object as object. Click on bind at the beginning of the animation (both objects should be in the same location). Make sure, that your high poly model fits inside the low poly model.

You're a star - Thanks so much!

you are welcome
